# How to evaluate Elisp code contained in a string?

Tags: read, eval

The question pretty much says it all: I have a string containing the source code for a valid Elisp expression, and I would like to evaluate it.

(In Python, for example, the expression `eval("1 - 2 + 3")` evaluates to 2.)

Comment: Note, `(calc-eval "1 - 2 + 3")` fits your python example better even if this is not valid elisp. If you do not yet require the `calc` package you need to load it before with `(require 'calc)`. (I know that this does not answer your question. Hence it is formulated as comment.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Evaluating a string of elisp code is a two-stage process: you need to parse the string using [`read-from-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Functions.html#index-read_002dfrom_002dstring) and then evaluate the resulting Lisp expression with [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval.html#index-eval).

```el
(defun my-eval-string (string)
  "Evaluate elisp code stored in a string."
  (eval (car (read-from-string string))))
```

Now `(my-eval-string "(+ 1 2)")` evaluates to `3`.

**Edit:**

As pointed out by **@lunaryorn**, `read-from-string` *reads the first expression only*, so this should be better:

```el
(defun my-eval-string (string)
  (eval (car (read-from-string (format "(progn %s)" string)))))
```

**Edit 2:**

To evaluate elisp code for side effects one could also use [`with-temp-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html#index-with_002dtemp_002dbuffer) and [`eval-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval.html#index-eval_002dbuffer) (`eval-buffer` always returns `nil`).

```el
(defun my-eval-string-for-side-effects (string)
  "Evaluate a string of elisp code for side effects."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert string)
    (eval-buffer)))

(my-eval-string-for-side-effects "(message \"hello!\")")
```

Comment: `with-temp-buffer` is less than ideal because it will mess up with all buffer-related calls, e.g. `buffer-file-name`, ...

Answer (score 6):

The answer of Constantine is okay.

Just to provide a slight modification:

```el
(defun my-eval-string (str)
  "Read and evaluate all forms in str.
Return the results of all forms as a list."
  (let ((next 0)
        ret)
    (condition-case err
        (while t
          (setq ret (cons (funcall (lambda (ret)
                                     (setq next (cdr ret))
                                     (eval (car ret)))
                                   (read-from-string str next))
                          ret)))
      (end-of-file))
    (nreverse ret)))

(my-eval-string "1 2 3 (+ 3 1)")
```

The last form returns the list `(1 2 3 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to evaluate elisp in a string only if it actually was valid elisp. Otherwise I just wanted the string as-is.

```lisp
(defun maybe-eval-string (string)
  "Maybe evaluate elisp in a given STRING."
  (or (ignore-errors
    (eval (car (read-from-string (format "(progn %s)" string))))
    ) string))


(print (maybe-eval-string "(format \"hello, %s\" \"world\")"))
(print (maybe-eval-string "hello, world"))
```

Output:

```
"hello, world"

"hello, world"
```

Full credit to @Constantine's answer. I just wrapped it in an `or` and `ignore-errors` but I though it was handy enough function to post as an answer.