# How should you read a Lisp file as Lisp for processing without condition-case?

Tags: read

To help catch predictable errors, I've written [my own linting tasks](https://github.com/vermiculus/ghub-plus/blob/e379073c2d07112326d236718c847ef4ce29396f/test/ghub%2B-test.el#L14) that read the code and [report any inconsistencies it finds](https://github.com/vermiculus/ghub-plus/blob/e379073c2d07112326d236718c847ef4ce29396f/test/test-helper.el#L79).  One of the hackier pieces to this right now is the following function:

```
(defun lint-get-forms (filename)
  "Read FILENAME and return a list of its Lisp forms."
  (let ((pos 0) forms)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file-contents filename)
      (condition-case _
          (while t
            (when-let ((cell (read-from-string (buffer-string) pos)))
              (push (car cell) forms)
              (goto-char (setq pos (cdr cell)))))
        (error forms)))
    forms))
```

Is there a better way to do this (preferably without `condition-case`)?

<sub>Ideally these checks would be done at compile-time, but they're not stable enough yet to move to the other repository.</sub>

Comment: Why convert buffer text to a string and read from that string? Why not read directly from the buffer? The latter is typically how to read from a Lisp file.

Comment: @Drew Hence why I'm posting this question :-) I think I neglected to consider `read`'s optional argument.

Comment: Got it. It's a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Drew's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24628/15748) to a related question.

If you do not mind ignoring all errors (I do not know which errors `read` might signal), you should use `ignore-errors`. Otherwise, your error handler should probably be specific to `end-of-file` errors.

Personally, I take (sometimes guilty) pleasure in K&R-style and functional brevity, so I would write your function like this:

```el
(defun lint-get-forms (filename)
  "Read FILENAME and return a list of its Lisp forms."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((buf (current-buffer))
          forms)
      (insert-file-contents filename)
      (while (ignore-errors (push (read buf) forms)))
      (nreverse forms))))
```

Regardless of whether you find this `while` form too terse, I recommend using `read` over `read-from-string`, as the former is much more powerful in the type of its argument. If, for some reason I am missing, you are intent on using `read-from-string`, I suggest caching the result of `buffer-string`.

P.S. Is there a reason you are calling `goto-char`?

Comment: re `goto-char`: `read-string` does not advance point. And terse is fine by me :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, but you were already passing an updated `pos` to `read-from-string`.