# Load a list from a file (in a script)

Tags: files, load

I have a script containing this code:

```el
(let
    ((JOURNALS
      '(

        ("abhandlungen aus dem mathematischen seminar der hamburgischen universitet" .
         "Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg") ;; inSPIRE

        ("acm transactions on mathematical software" .
         "ACM Trans. Math. Software") ;; inSPIRE

        ("acs applied materials and interfaces" .
         "ACS Appl. Mater. Interfaces") ;; NLM Catalog

        )))

  ...

  )
```

and I need move the list of cons cells in a separate file. E.g.:

```el
(let
    ((JOURNALS
      '( (read-file "list-of-cons-cells.el")

        )))

  ...

  )
```

Where the `list-of-cons-cells.el` file contents is:

```el
("abhandlungen aus dem mathematischen seminar der hamburgischen universitet" .
 "Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg") ;; inSPIRE

("acm transactions on mathematical software" .
 "ACM Trans. Math. Software") ;; inSPIRE

("acs applied materials and interfaces" .
 "ACS Appl. Mater. Interfaces") ;; NLM Catalog
```

What's the right way to load this file when I run my script?

**Edit.** This is a MWE of mi original idea (this is not the real function...):

```el
(defun myfunction-orig ()
  (interactive) 
  (let ((JOURNALS '(

                    ("abhandlungen aus dem mathematischen seminar der hamburgischen universitet" .
                     "Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg") ;; inSPIRE

                    ("acm transactions on mathematical software" .
                     "ACM Trans. Math. Software") ;; inSPIRE

                    ("acs applied materials and interfaces" .
                     "ACS Appl. Mater. Interfaces") ;; NLM Catalog

                    )
                  ))

    ;; Debug:
    (princ JOURNALS)
    (sit-for 2)

    (while JOURNALS
      (read-string (car (car JOURNALS)))
      (setq JOURNALS (cdr JOURNALS)))))
```

I tried to modified it on phils' suggestion:

```el
(defun myfunction ()
  (interactive) 
  (with-temp-buffer 
    (insert-file-contents "./list-of-cons-cells.el")
    (let (JOURNALS form)
      (while (setq form (ignore-errors (read (current-buffer))))
        (push form JOURNALS))
      (nreverse JOURNALS)

      ;; Debug:
      (princ JOURNALS)
      (sit-for 2)

      (while JOURNALS
        (read-string (car (car JOURNALS)))
        (setq JOURNALS (cdr JOURNALS)))

      )))
```

but it doesn't work.

**Solution.** This is the solution based on the edited phils' answer:

```el
(defun myfunction ()
  (interactive) 
  (let ((JOURNALS (with-temp-buffer
                    (insert-file-contents "./list-of-cons-cells.el")
                    (let (list form)
                      (while (setq form (ignore-errors
                                          (read (current-buffer))))
                        (push form list))
                      (nreverse list))))) 
    ;; Debug
    (princ JOURNALS)
    (sit-for 5)

    (while JOURNALS
      (read-string (car (car JOURNALS)))
      (setq JOURNALS (cdr JOURNALS)))))
```

Comment: I suggest that you insert the file into a temporary buffer and iteratively `read` each form from that buffer.

Comment: @phils I know how to use `with-temp-buffer` but I'm not sure of what you mean with "iteratively read each form from that buffer".

Comment: see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33586/how-to-read-elisp-file-into-s-expression

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi What is the desired return value or outcome of the `myfunction` function you've added to the question?  (You have done something really strange with the code I suggested.)

Comment: @phils Sorry, My mistake. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines?

```el
(let ((JOURNALS (with-temp-buffer
                  (insert-file-contents FILENAME)
                  (let (list form)
                    (while (setq form (ignore-errors
                                        (read (current-buffer))))
                      (push form list))
                    (nreverse list)))))
  ...)
```

Comment: I get this error: `while: Wrong type argument: stringp, ("acs applied materials and interfaces" . "ACS Appl. Mater. Interfaces")`

Comment: I edite mi question with a minimal "not working" example

Comment: You're passing a cons cell as the prompt argument to `read-string` in the code you've added, and the prompt must be a string.

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question.

Comment: Please note the edit to my answer.  You misinterpreted the original code -- it's important that you're using the *return value* of `nreverse`, but the way you've used the code you're ignoring it, which means your `JOURNALS` is pointing only to the final element of the list.  The revised answer ought to make it more obvious how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw the burden of iterating onto lisp's `read`.
To do that you just need to realize that the list in journals is a lisp list with the beginning and ending parentheses missing. So fill-in the missing and read.

[Ive renamed your `list-of-cons-cells.el` to `journals.txt` since its a lisp data-structure but not lisp code]

```
(with-temp-buffer
    (insert "(")
    (insert-file-contents "journals.txt")
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert ")")       
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (read (current-buffer)))
```

Comment: This also seems like a good solution. Do you think it is better for performance? (My list is huge).

Comment: Well… Dunno! "Huge" is quite a relative term with machines nowadays having gigabytes of memory, megabytes of list may not be large. OTOH  you *are* creating the list one way or other in memory — with or without read. So why not let the system do it? Bottom line (for performance questions): **Test!** Push huge to hugher until it breaks and see which version breaks first. And when!!

Comment: You're right, the term huge is inappropriate for the list itself (that is a big list), but is more appropriate for the tasks I do with it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi : In issues of performance a kind of blindness is typical and endemic. "Miss the wood for the trees" "Penny-wise pound-foolish" etc are sayings that come to mind. If performance in the sense of size/number of tasks you are subjecting your list to is an issue, you may seriously want to consider a language other than elisp. eg in python you have numpy numba etc. Then you have performance-oriented languages like Julia. Then theres sqlite and the whole menagerie of database systems... Etc

Comment: Also if lisp is your thing, classic lisps (not emacs variety) can beat the pants off not just elisp but many of today's fashionable scripting languages