# How to read multiple expressions from stream?

Tags: read

When calling `(read "(+ 1 2) (+ 2 3)")`, I get `(+ 1 2)`, as expected. How can I get the next expression, namely `(+ 2 3)`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

`"(+ 1 2) (+ 2 3)"` is not a stream, it is a string. Strings do not keep track of what has been read already and what should be read next, so if you call `read` on this string multiple times you will always get the first expression.

You probably want to read from a buffer instead. Calling `read` on a buffer will move `point` in that buffer as it goes, allowing the next call to `read` to pick up where the first left off.

See [chapter 20.2 Input Streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Streams.html) in the Elisp manual for more information.

Comment: The question may well be an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you're really trying to do? (Maybe @db48x has guessed correctly what you want to know, in which case great.) But `read` reads a single expression from its argument (a string in this case), and you passed it a string with two expressions. It read an expression from the string you gave it, and it returned that expression, `(+ 1 2)`.

Comment: In fairness the signature is `(read &optional STREAM)` and "STREAM or the value of ‘standard-input’ may be: ... a string (takes text from string, starting at the beginning)".  That "starting at the beginning" part is the key here of course, as you've pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the link to X-Y question. I am prompting the user with a minibuffer, and asking them to input s-expressions. So they might say ```(+ 1 2)``` and I want to read that and store it as s-expression. But I also want to support ```(+ 1 2) (+ 2 3)``` in the minibuffer as well so that I may read in multiple s-expressions at once.

Answer (score 1):

I slightly modified the answer in [How should you read a Lisp file as Lisp for processing without condition-case?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32811/how-should-you-read-a-lisp-file-as-lisp-for-processing-without-condition-case) to get

```
(defun read-multiple (string)
  "Read STRING and return a list of its Lisp forms."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((buf (current-buffer))
          forms)
      (insert string)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (ignore-errors (push (read buf) forms)))
      (nreverse forms))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read all the expressions from the string `"(+ 1 2) (+ 2 3)"` just wrap it by an extra pair of parantheses to represent a list, i.e., read `"((+ 1 2) (+ 2 3))"` instead.

The following Elisp snippets give you a hint how to do that:

```el
(let ((str "(+ 1 2) (+ 2 3)"))
  (read (concat "(" str ")")))
```

or

```el
(let ((str "(+ 1 2) (+ 2 3)"))
  (read (format "(%s)" str)))
```

Thereafter, you can iterate over the list with `dolist` or `cl-loop for ... in ... do`.

Comment: This does seem more elegant, thank you.